# joomla too many articles -- retrive from a different location?

Tags: joomla

The Joomla! site that I am hosting is nearing 10,000 articles and interfering with the size of backing up Joomla (nearing 4GB+). Is there any mechanism or plugin for storing the articles off-site (ie in a server folder) not with the Joomla core?

Is there an upper limit to how many articles a typical non-optimized Joomla site can hold?

Thanks

Comment: Article are stored in the database, not in any files. If your site is growing rapidly with all these articles, you might want to consider upgrading to a hosting package that's more suitable to big sites.

Answer (score 1):

As Lodder mentioned, articles are in your database, so should have no impact on your site backups.  You need to look at where all the space in your folders is being used. There's a free program called [SpaceMonger v1.4.0](http://www.sixty-five.cc/download/) (near the bottom of the page) that gives you a visual layout of how much space is being used.  We use it quite frequently when our backups are getting huge, and often find tons of temporary files that have long expired.

Comment: Would also suggest Admin Tools to clean the temp directory on the site. Will help massively if it crammed full of files